# Listener to execute at the end of the input file

Tags: jberet

I have a process that uses a chunk to read a file and insert the records into a table. I need to be able to insert a row into a parent table at the opening of the input file and when the file is closed I need to update that parent table row inserted at the start. Is there a listener or approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest one is [StepListener](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/batch/api/listener/StepListener.html), where you can implement its `beforeStep` and `afterStep` method to update the parent table. You can inject `StepContext` into the step listener class to access context data through step metrics or step transient data.

But `beforeStep` is called before opening the input file. Not sure if this diff is significant for your case.

Otherwise, you can implement your own item reader class to achieve your requirement.

Comment: I ended up using a ChunkListener, beforeChunk and afterChunk.